# Java Runtime Error python pip install package in big sur

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv

i am trying to install cv2 package.

```sh
sudo apt install python-opencv
```

while run above line getting error below:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports apt.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.
```

Comment: Try to install Java and put it on PATH

Comment: That would not work. He is trying to download a package completely unrelated to Java.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: the following answer assumes that you use MacOS, which I suspect you do. If you are not using this OS then this solution will not work.**

Apparently, the error has nothing to do with installing the package. In the past Java used to ship with a tool called `apt`. To manage installations on Linux you need to use the `Advanced Package Tool`, which is probably what you tried to do. This won't work on MacOS however! You need to use the `brew` command, which is the `apt` equivalent for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

`apt` is not supported on MacOS.

Please try again,

`sudo brew install python-opencv`